# Passing on an Interface as a constructor to a class

Tags: java, interface

Here's My code:

```
public interface Baseinterface {}
abstract class Interface1 implements Baseinterface{}
abstract class Interface2 implements Baseinterface{}

public interface Classinterface {}
```

And i want to use this code:

```
public class Myclass(Baseinterface interfaceversion) implements  Classinterface{}
```

Where the kind of interface implementation is passed as a constructor. 
So when a function is defined in both of those abstract classes my actual class knows which one to use. I am fairly new at java.
Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to make a form of multiple inheritance, which most I believe will agree is bad in java.  If you want a class to be able to select different implementations on an instance per instance basis, I would suggest forgoing an inheritance based solution, and instead, have your MyClass instance contain an instance field of the interface implementation to be used.  This can still be passed in as a constructor.

Comment: And how do i do that? :)

Comment: What does "Iam confused here a bit" mean? What is the problem with the code you posted? What don't you understand?

Comment: Do you mean `public class Myclass<Interface extends Baseinterface> implements  Classinterface` ?

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding the nature of the question, but here goes:

Given this code which describes two abstract classes that implement the same method as defined by an interface:

```
interface BaseInterface {
    void foo();
}

abstract class ITestA implements BaseInterface {
    public void foo() {
        System.out.print("A");
    }
}

abstract class ITestB implements BaseInterface {
    public void foo() {
        System.out.print("B");
    }
}

public class MyClass {
    private BaseInterface enclosed;

    MyClass(BaseInterface base) {
        enclosed = base;
    }

    public void foo() {
        enclosed.foo(); // call the implementation specific to the instance passed in by constructor
    }
}
```

This could be called like:

```
    public class Test {
    void bar() {
        // This may look weird cause we're defining an anonymous implementation of the abstract class, without adding any new implementation details
        ITestA impl = new ITestA() {}; 

        MyClass myClass = new MyClass(impl);
        myClass.foo(); // prints "A"
    }
}
```